# itunesconnect edit metadata

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

My first app just went live and I am thrilled. Now I've discovered that the images could be in better order. Is it possible to do that now, or is it too late?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just edit them in iTunes Connect. They'll update within a few hours.